# Highcharts Heatmap - How to get blocks next to each other when separated by more then '1' in value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

Attached is an image of the problem I'm currently having.[image]

Attached is an example of the issue manually created with JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ekjrLsz2/

My goal is to have each of the blocks be next to each other without all the space in-between like the default demos for the heatmap show.

I can get it to work correctly if the data is going 1 by 1, for example; 1,2,3,4,5,6

But if the data is going 5,10,15,20, etc... then you get what you see in my attached image.

So to be more clear the X direction is going 1 by 1 in my demo image and shows without spacing, the Y direction however has the large spacing since the data does not have numbers 21,22,23,24 or the space inbetween every 5 so to speak.

Below is the code I use to generate the chart.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang: {
                    decimalPoint: '.',
                    thousandsSep: ','
                }
            });

            Highcharts.chart('heatmap-container', {
    
                chart: {
                    type: 'heatmap',
                    marginTop: 40,
                    marginBottom: 80,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1
                },
            
            
                title: {
                    text: 'Report Data'
                },
            
                xAxis: {
                    //categories: ['1%', '2%', '3%', '4%', '5%', '6%', '7%', '8%', '9%', '10%'],
                    title: {text:$('#x-values').val()},
                    //showEmpty:true,
                },
            
                yAxis: {
                    categories: ['5', '10', '15', '20', '25'],
                    title: {text:$('#y-values').val()},
                    reversed: false,
                    //visible: true,
                    //showEmpty:true,
                },
            
                 colorAxis: {
                  max: goodColorVal,
                  min: badColorVal,
                  reversed: false,
                  tickInterval: 1,
                    //min: -150,
                    //minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    //maxColor: '#00FF00',//Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4]
                    stops: [
                      [0.0,'#FF0000'],
                      [0.5,'#FFFFFF'],
                      [1.0,"#00FF00"]]
                }, 
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    margin: 0,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 25,
                    symbolHeight: 280,
                    reversed:true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '',
                    pointFormat: `<b style="text-transform:capitalize;">${$("#x-values option:selected").text()}</b>:{point.x:,.2f} - <b style="text-transform:capitalize;">${$("#y-values option:selected").text()}</b>:{point.y:,.2f} - <b style="text-transform:capitalize;">${$("#z-values option:selected").text()}</b>:{point.value:,.2f}`
                    // formatter: function () {
                    //     return '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    //         this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'y') + '</b>';
                    // }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Report Data For Input 1',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    //data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 9], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
                    data: arraydata, //[[0,0,-87],[1,0,22],[2,0,33],[3,0,55]],
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                }],
                responsive: {
                    rules: [{
                        condition: {
                            maxWidth: 500
                        },
                        chartOptions: {
                            yAxis: {
                                labels: {
                                    formatter: function () {
                                        return this.value.charAt(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            
            });
```

I have tried pointInterval and tickInterval with no luck so far.

Comment: Data array accepts `[row, col, value]`. so If you will skip data points, it will definitely show hole / empty-columns. Instead, just provide data you want to render and use  `tickPositioner` to generate custom ticks to show that the `x axes` is increasing by 2

Comment: Can you show me with a JSFiddle if you don't mind? I added it to my question to make it easier to show the example.  I can change the ticks easily enough, in fact they are already correct, the bigger concern is getting the squares to be next to each other so the space is used efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to have your points next to each other (without any spaces) is to give them x attributes without skipping any number, e.g 1,2,3,4...
Why don't you try to do it this way?

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/39vx468s/

To skip the empty spaces between points you can use breaks functionality.

API references:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/et4kryvz/

```
xAxis: {
 breaks: [{
  from: 0.5,
  to: 1.5,
  breakSize: 0
 }]
}
```

There is also another solution, which uses colsize and rowsize properties. Thanks to that you can avoid using the breaks altogether this way and it even works with floating-point data.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/87tL3ogh/1/

Comment: I'm going to give this a try, never thought about using breaks! will report back end of day with results.  Thank you!!

Comment: I got it working here (https://jsfiddle.net/87tL3ogh/), you can use repeat to make it repeat on every cycle!

Comment: update your answer with what I put in the jsfiddle if you don't mind

Comment: here is a new jsfiddle I found an even better answer using rowsize and colsize (https://jsfiddle.net/87tL3ogh/1/), you can avoid using the breaks altogether this way and it even works with floating point data!

Comment: Congrats on finding another solution. It seems to work fine. :)

Comment: Thanks, if you wanted to add my answer as edit to yours so people can see that also would appreciate it, otherwise I can make a separate answer.  I'd like to give you credit for it though.

Comment: Sure, I've added it. Thanks